# AngularJS: why does my dropdown have an initial blank entry?

Tags: angularjs

I am fetching some JSON frm a server and using it to populate a combobox.

A JSON entry looks like this

```
    "campaign_id": "2",
    "customer_id": "1",
    "title": "Purple monkey dishwasher",
    "description": "perfectly cromulent",
    "start_time": "19/09/2015 09:42:06",
    "end_time": "19/10/2015 09:42:06"
```

And I declare my drop down thus-wise

```
<select name="SelectCampaignForConnections" 
 ng-model="connectionsCampaignDropDown" 
 ng-options="campaign.title for campaign in campaigns"  
 ng-change="ShowConnectionsForCampaign(connectionsCampaignDropDown)">
```

I initialize the model of the select ...

```
    $http.get(url)   
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
            {
               if ($scope.connections.length > 0)
                   $scope.connectionsCampaignDropDown = $scope.connections[0];
```

When the dropdown shows, it contains the `title` element of each JSON entry, ***BUT***, it has an initial blank entry.

What am I doing wrongsomely?

---

[Update] @sheilak gave a good anser :

> In order for the dropdown to defaulted to a non-blank value, the value
>   of the variable passed to ng-model must equal one of the options
>   passed to ng-options.
>
> In your case where ng-options is populated by values of
>   campaign.title, it looks like the value passed to ng-model i.e.
>   connectionsCampaignDropDown should be populated with
>   $scope.connections[0].title rather than the whole object
>   $scope.connections[0].
>
> $scope.connectionsCampaignDropDown = $scope.connections[0].title;

***However***, I would prefer to pass around an complete object, rather than just a field of it.

Can this be done?

(if not, then I will have to pass only the title to the ng-change function ShowConnectionsForCampaign() and it will then have to loop over the data to find a match, which seems inefficient)

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that without looping over the data but would be interested to see an alternative solution if someone else has one

Comment: I don't know where to say thanks for that bounty (maybe a little premature of me to assume it's for me) but I really appreciate it: Thank you. :-)) (sorry if this comment doesn't adhere to the comment guidelines)

Comment: I have to wait 24 hours, but then you have 200 points coming. maybe I should have made it more?

Comment: I have to wait 24 hours, but then you have 200 points coming. maybe I should have made it more?

Comment: no, you shouldn't've made it more!  Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name="SelectCampaignForConnections" 
    ng-init="justGiveItAName=getInitialSelection()"
    ng-model="justGiveItAName" 
    ng-options="campaign.title for campaign in campaigns"  
    ng-change="ShowConnectionsForCampaign(justGiveItAName)">
```

where getInitialSelection() is a function on your scope that could take a param if you need it to, but I would probably go with something like this in the case you outline above:

```
function getInitialSelection() {return connections[0]};
```

or set it directly in the `ng-init`:

```
ng-init="$scope.connections[0]"
```

(you might have to fiddle with the above code - I haven't tested it).

btw - 'justGiveItAName' is then an object available elsewhere.

I have now tested it; see these Fiddles for working examples:

Setting directly in ng-init: http://jsfiddle.net/lukkea/nuo2c3Lk/

Using a function on the $scope: http://jsfiddle.net/lukkea/o6strxjf/

Passing the object instead of properties (as the OP requested): http://jsfiddle.net/lukkea/fsx8s67j/2/

Passing the objects in and object back: http://jsfiddle.net/lukkea/ww9yqsrm/3/

Comment: Would it be valid to pass the option  `campaign` to `getInitialSelection()` ?

Comment: yes - that would be fine; I am just working on a jsFiddle for you to demonstrate this, but have a few other things going on too, so I might be longer than you might expect... :-)

Comment: I can't wait for that fiddle :-)

Comment: I went as fast as I could! ;-) Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/lukkea/nuo2c3Lk/

Comment: Thanks!  That will help others. Alas, it doesn't work for me. I suspect that @JakubJudas is correct, but I can't figure out how to fix it. `getInitialSelection()` returns the correct string, but it doesn't match any of he `ng-option`s an an object, just as a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90153/discussion-between-lukkea-and-mawg).

Comment: I can't believe that you have put in so much work!!  I don't think I have ever received quite such a comprehensive answer in all of my years on S.O.("question eligible for bounty tomorrow")

Comment: At the risk of being too chatty, thank you. It's a pleasure to help and I'm glad I was on the right lines and didn't waste your time. :-))

Answer (score 2):

In order for the dropdown to defaulted to a non-blank value, the value of the variable passed to `ng-model` must equal one of the options passed to `ng-options`.

In your case where `ng-options` is populated by values of `campaign.title`, it looks like the value passed to `ng-model` i.e. `connectionsCampaignDropDown` should be populated with `$scope.connections[0].title` rather than the whole object `$scope.connections[0]`.

```
$scope.connectionsCampaignDropDown = $scope.connections[0].title;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible, you just have to make sure that the initial value you set is the exact same object (not just another object with the same values)

Comment: Could you explain what that means?

Comment: I see that you are using campaigns as your model for the dropdown, but you set an element from connections as the default value - angular needs the two to be a reference to the same object. i.e. if you had var obj1 = {"campaign_id": "2"...}

connectons[0]=obj1, campaigns[0]=obj1, that would work. But if you had connections[0]=obj1, campaigns[0] = {"campaign_id": "2"...}, that would not

(sorry for the bad formatting)

Comment: where do you get the connections and campaigns?

Comment: I fetch them as JSON from a server

Comment: Each of them from a diffferent endpoint, right?
I would make a service that loads the campaigns and keeps them as an array, and then when loading the connection I would have a service replace the loaded connection with an element from that array (unfortunately that would require iterating through the array) - possibly extending the original object with the new values through angular.extend if you need that for anything

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `campaign as campaign.title for campaign in campaigns` in `ng-options`.

Then it stores the selected `campaign` object in the model (not just the value of `campaign.title`) and the label shown in the dropdown will still be `campaign.title`.

```
<select name="SelectCampaignForConnections" 
        ng-model="connectionsCampaignDropDown" 
        ng-options="campaign as campaign.title for campaign in campaigns"  
        ng-change="ShowConnectionsForCampaign(connectionsCampaignDropDown)">
```

The expression used here is: `select` as `label` for `value` in `array`.

- `select` - the value stored in `ng-model`
- `label` - the text displayed in the dropdown

The different expression options are listed in [the official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).